# Merge sorted data with sql

Tags: sql, group-by, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have data like this:

```
+---+----+----------+--------+
| id|hash|start_date|end_date|
+---+----+----------+--------+
|  1|   a|      2012|    2013|
|  1|   b|      2014|    2015|
|  1|   a|      2016|    2017|
|  1|   a|      2018|    2019|
+---+----+----------+--------+
```

and I want to merge periods that has same values. 
In the result I would like to have data like this:

```
+---+----+----------+--------+
| id|hash|start_date|end_date|
+---+----+----------+--------+
|  1|   a|      2012|    2013|
|  1|   b|      2014|    2015|
|  1|   a|      2016|    2019|
+---+----+----------+--------+
```

(last two rows are merged into one period)

I tried such a query:

```
%sql
select distinct 
 id, 
 hash,  
 min(start_date)  over(partition by hash) as start_date,  
 max(end_date) over(partition by hash) as  end_date 
from (
 select 1 as id, 'a' as hash, 2012 as start_date, 2013 as end_date
  union 
 select 1 as id, 'b' as hash, 2014 as start_date, 2015 as end_date
  union 
 select 1 as id, 'a' as hash, 2016 as start_date, 2017 as end_date
  union 
 select 1 as id, 'a' as hash, 2018 as start_date, 2019 as end_date
) t
```

and the result is

```
+---+----+----------+--------+
| id|hash|start_date|end_date|
+---+----+----------+--------+
|  1|   a|      2012|    2019|
|  1|   b|      2014|    2015|
+---+----+----------+--------+
```

which is wrong, because period 2012-2013 and 2016-2019 should be separated.

How can I achieve correct result with Spark SQL?

Answer (score 1):

This is a gap-and-islands problem.  The simplest method is the difference of row numbers.  This will work assuming you have no gaps:

```
select id, hash, min(start_date) as start_date, max(end_date) as max_end_date
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, hash order by start_date) as seqnum_h,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by start_date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id, hash, (seqnum - seqnum_h)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem. Here is one approach that uses `lag()` and a window `sum` to define the groups. The upside of this approach is that it would allow concurrent periods series over different `id`s.

Consider:

```
select id, hash, min(start_date) start_date, max(end_date) end_date
from (
    select
        t.*,
        sum(case when start_date = lag_end_date + 1 then 0 else 1 end)
            over(partition by id, hash order by end_date) grp
    from (
        select 
            t.*, 
            lag(end_date) over(partition by id, hash order by end_date) lag_end_date
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by id, hash, grp
order by id, min(start_date)
```